# No sqlbrowser in SQL Configuration

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea, ssms, sqlbrowser

I have installed sql express server and management studio 18 and I have a problem connecting it to intellij idea. I have looked all over the Internet and everywhere they write that you need to run sqlbrowser, but I don't see it in sql configuration and in services. However, I have it installed in the C: \ Program Files \ Microsoft SQL Server \ 90 \ Shared folder.
I tried to run it through the console but it was unsuccessful[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPE6a.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnHQV.png)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I was still able to connect.

First step: disable antivirus

Second step: go to the console through the administrator and enter cd C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlbrowser.exe -c

sqlbrowser will not appear in services, but now you can connect to the database